# Глобализация стилей, структура scss стилей

Tags: scss

Насколько правильной практикой является разделение CSS классов по отдельным файлам для крупных проектов?
На выходе для следующего CSS кода:

```
.app {
    display: block;
}
.app__item {
    display: block;
}
.app__item-text {
    display: block;
}
```

Получается следующая структура .scss файлов

Папка: App

- Файл app.scss
- Файл app__item.scss
- Файл app__item-text.scss

Comment: Нормальная практика. БЭМ считает так же
https://ru.bem.info/methodology/filestructure/

Comment: вы для каждого css-класса в проекте собираетесь заводить отдельный файл?